# Using a basic function of CGAL, e.g. `square`

Tags: c++, cgal

I am starting to work my way through CGAL and have a question about the [Algebraic foundations](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Algebraic_foundations/index.html) package.

How do you use the `square` function defined [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/de64da240dd6ea3c56cbbd55a2c53caac0c82370/Algebraic_foundations/include/CGAL/number_utils.h#L66-L72)?

I tried the following

```
// tmp.cpp
#include <CGAL/number_utils.h>

int main() {
  double dist = 0.002;
  auto sq_dist = CGAL::square(dist);
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler throws the following error message

```sh
$ make tmp
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target tmp
[ 14%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tmp.dir/tmp.cpp.o
In file included from /home/USER/info/cgal/tmp/tmp.cpp:1:
/home/USER/info/cgal/Algebraic_foundations/include/CGAL/number_utils.h: In instantiation of ‘typename CGAL::Algebraic_structure_traits<Type_>::Square::result_type CGAL::square(const AS&) [with AS = double; typename CGAL::Algebraic_structure_traits<Type_>::Square::result_type = CGAL::Null_tag; typename CGAL::Algebraic_structure_traits<Type_>::Square = CGAL::Null_functor]’:
/home/USER/info/cgal/tmp/tmp.cpp:5:30:   required from here
/home/USER/info/cgal/Algebraic_foundations/include/CGAL/number_utils.h:71:18: error: no match for call to ‘(CGAL::Algebraic_structure_traits<double>::Square {aka CGAL::Null_functor}) (const double&)’
   71 |     return square( x );
      |            ~~~~~~^~~~~
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/tmp.dir/build.make:146: CMakeFiles/tmp.dir/tmp.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/tmp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:90: CMakeFiles/tmp.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:124: tmp] Error 2
```

It is mentioned in this [github issue](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/5123#issuecomment-717153065).

---

**Update**: Following the comment by @MarcGlisse I changed the header include to

```
// tmp.cpp
#include <CGAL/number_utils.h>
#include <CGAL/basic.h>

int main() {
  double dist = 0.002;
  auto sq_dist = CGAL::square(dist);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation runs through smoothly but linking throws new errors

```sh
$ make tmp
[ 14%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tmp.dir/tmp.cpp.o
[ 28%] Linking CXX executable tmp
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/tmp.dir/tmp.cpp.o: in function `main':
/home/USER/info/cgal/STL_Extension/include/CGAL/exceptions.h:88: multiple definition of `main'; /usr/bin/ld: DWARF error: section .debug_str is larger than its filesize! (0x32f0bc2 vs 0x2447b28)
/usr/bin/ld: DWARF error: section .debug_str is larger than its filesize! (0x32f0bc2 vs 0x2447b28)
/usr/bin/ld: DWARF error: section .debug_str is larger than its filesize! (0x32f0bc2 vs 0x2447b28)
...
```

The referenced line `STL_Extension/include/CGAL/exceptions.h:88` can be found [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/de64da240dd6ea3c56cbbd55a2c53caac0c82370/STL_Extension/include/CGAL/exceptions.h#L88).

---

**Update**: I found the issue (see my answer) but it doesnt make sense to me. Why am I not able to have multiple `main` functions in different files in the same folder?

I built the following way

```sh
cd ${CGAL_DIR}/tmp
cgal_create_CMakeLists -s tmp
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .
make tmp
```

Comment: You are missing some includes. Easiest would be to include `CGAL/basic.h`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Now I get an error at link time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you followed the instructions here: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/usage.html ?

Comment: @bolov Yes. I can build other programs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue arises because of the `-s tmp` argument.

The solution is to call it in either of the following formats

```
cgal_create_CMakeLists tmp
cgal_create_CMakeLists
```

The documentation gives an explanation

```sh
$ cgal_create_CMakeLists -h
Usage: cgal_create_CMakeLists [-s source] ...
...
  -s source If this parameter is given the script will create one single executable for 'source' with all source files; otherwise it creates one executable for each main'ed source.
...
```

There is no reasonable way to create *one* executable for files containing *multiple* `main` functions.

Answer (score 0):

The following example (**cgal_ex.cpp**) works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2 Point_2;

int main()
{
  Point_2 p(0,0), q(3,4);
  std::cout << "p = " << p << std::endl;
  std::cout << "q = " << q.x() << " " << q.y() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "sqdist(p,q) = "
            << CGAL::squared_distance(p,q) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

```
g++ cgal_ex.cpp; a.out
p = 0 0
q = 3 4
sqdist(p,q) = 25
```

Reference: [https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/tutorial_hello_world.html][1]

Adding example of a Makefile for two files having main in the same directory:

```
MODULES=cgal_ex cgal_ex1
%: %.cpp
        g++ -O2 -o $@ $<
        strip $@
%: %.c
        gcc -o $@ $<
        strip $@
clean:
        -rm -rf $(MODULES)
all: $(MODULES)
```

Usage example:

```
make all -f Makefile.cgal
g++ -O2 -o cgal_ex cgal_ex.cpp
strip cgal_ex
g++ -O2 -o cgal_ex1 cgal_ex1.cpp
strip cgal_ex1
```

Usage example with **cgal_create_CMakeLists**.
Source: https://github.com/CGAL/releases/blob/main/scripts/cgal_create_CMakeLists

Usage example:

1. Create new directory, which has 3 files only:

```
cgal_create_CMakeLists  cgal_ex.cpp  cgal_ex1.cpp
```

2. Run the following commands:

```
cmake $PWD
make
```

Results:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Using header-only CGAL
-- Targetting Unix Makefiles
-- Using /usr/bin/c++ compiler.
-- Found GMP: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so  
-- Found MPFR: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpfr.so  
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.71.0", minimum required is "1.48")  
-- Boost include dirs: /usr/include
-- Boost libraries:    
-- Using gcc version 4 or later. Adding -frounding-math
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.71.0")  
CMake Warning at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/CGAL/CGAL_enable_end_of_configuration_hook.cmake:99 (message):
  =======================================================================
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9999 (CGAL_run_at_the_end_of_configuration)


-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/<username>/cgal

Scanning dependencies of target cgal_ex1
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cgal_ex1.dir/cgal_ex1.cpp.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable cgal_ex1
[ 50%] Built target cgal_ex1
Scanning dependencies of target cgal_ex
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cgal_ex.dir/cgal_ex.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable cgal_ex
[100%] Built target cgal_ex

  [1]: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/tutorial_hello_world.html
  [2]: https://github.com/CGAL/releases/blob/main/scripts/cgal_create_CMakeLists
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Actually the only thing unclear is mentioned in the last update to my question (regarding multiple `main`s). Do you know an answer to that?

Comment: In order to answer this question, I need to see Makefile. I've updated my answer - provided example of the Makefile, which compiles 2 *cpp files, each one has its own main

Comment: I built using the CGAL specific built script `cgal_create_CMakeLists` (mentioned in my last update). It creates some Makefile and it seems like it does not work with multiple files containing `main` functions? Or I might just be using it wrong which is why I am asking for it...

Comment: This script worked fine for me. See updated answer