# CGAL: Which headers to include

Tags: c++, header-files, cgal

What is the standard workflow to figure out which headers are needed to make the program compile?

Take the following simple example

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout << CGAL::square(0.002) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

The function `square` is defined in [`Algebraic_foundations/include/CGAL/number_utils.h`](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/4d0b3e1d3ff85aa75c063dd8510d97dc9e8f87af/Algebraic_foundations/include/CGAL/number_utils.h#L66-L72).

Question 1: Why is it not enough to just `#include <CGAL/number_utils.h>`?

I was made aware that `#include <CGAL/basic.h>` makes the program compile.
I guess one can use a more fine-grained file inclusion and looking in `basic.h` I found out that `#include <CGAL/number_type_basic.h>` is enough.

Question 2: Does using a finer-grained file inclusion decrease compilation time (less text in compilation unit?) but executable/object files will not differ as compilers remove the excess code from unneeded inclusions?

Question 3: Is there another rationale why one would use finer inclusions?
Some kind of style guide?
Or is it even good practice to include a high-level header to make it safe against changes in low-level code?

Question 4: What kind of high-level headers are there in CGAL?
Is there one for the whole library?
How is the connection regarding all the different packages?
Is there one for each package?

Question 5: If it is good practice to include middle- to lower-level header files then what is the standard workflow to figure out which headers are needed, e.g. for the `square` function in the above mentioned example?

Comment: "*What is the standard workflow to figure out which headers are needed to make the program compile?*" Nothing standard, you have to look where the functions/classes you are using are defined.

Comment: As to Question 1: If your compiler knows to look for header files in `Algebraic_foundations/include/`, such as with a -I switch on the compiler invocation, then `<CGAL/number_utils.h>` will work.

Comment: @WaisKamal I explicitly only use the `CGAL::square` function which is defined in `number_utils.h`. It seems like this file depends on some basic framework which it doesn't include itself...?

Comment: @jkb The compiler finds `number_utils.h` but something else (?) seems to be missing. The compiler error was posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69335535/10774817).

Comment: For this particular case, `CGAL/number_utils.h` declares `square`, but you also need `CGAL/double.h` for the specialization for `double`. In practice, you usually include kernel headers that include more than enough of those basic headers so you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all reference manual pages such as this one of the class [`Triangulation_2`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Triangulation__2.html) give as very first information which header file to include.
All higher level data structures are parameterized with a *geometric traits class* for which they in most cases pass a kernel, e.g., the [`Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Exact__predicates__inexact__constructions__kernel.html), which again states what header to include.  The latter will define number types which include all the infrastructure.
Note that `CGAL/basic.h` is not documented.